# FQL - getting access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need someone help.

When I open https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ and clicked https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=blablabla, I got all page that I've liked.

My questions was, from where I got the access_token value? can I get it by script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook developer site leverages an internal test console application that all developers can use to test calls within the documentation, site automatically appends the access_token.

A next place one can find the access token is https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer with the Graph API Explorer app.

You can also get it via script by following one of the authentication flows described at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

You will need to create an application at https://developers.facebook.com/apps then,

For example via PHP using a server side flow,

- Redirect the user to the OAuth Dialog ($dialog_url shown below)
- A code will be given in response
- Exchange the code for a user access token ($token_url shown below)

```php
<?php 

   $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
   $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
   $my_url = "YOUR_URL";

   session_start();
   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_SESSION['state'] && ($_SESSION['state'] === $_REQUEST['state'])) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $likes = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     print_r($likes); // A dump of the likes data
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }

 ?>
```

See more of the reference information available at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/